LyX fails with SVG on Fedora 40
I have been using LyX for several years on Ubuntu. Now I had to move to Fedora 40, where I have installed LyX Version 2.4.1 (Monday, July 1, 2024) and Inkscape Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20ef0f, 2023-11-25) and I am facing issues with SVG files created in Inkscape.
In my terminal I can do
inkscape --export-area-page --export-type=pdf -o deleteme.pdf Inkscape_schematic.svg

and it works as expected.
In LyX I have these settings:

If I only enable the two on the top (that came shipped with LyX), it works but horrible. I created the converter SVG -> PDF (graphics) and now LyX is not even able to convert the images:

I also tried putting
inkscape --export-area-page --export-type=pdf -o $$p$$o $$p$$i

in my converter, with the same results.
How can I make it work nicely with SVG files?
Edit
I run LyX from the command line like this: lyx -dbg graphics deleteme.lyx and it prints this:
my_user@my_PC:~/Desktop/LyX_fails$ lyx -dbg graphics deleteme.lyx 
Debugging `graphics' (Graphics conversion and loading)
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=latex, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dvi, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=tgif, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=fig, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dia, flags=10
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=odg, flags=10
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=agr, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=fen, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=svg, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=svgz, flags=10
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=bmp, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=gif, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=jpg, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pbm, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pgm, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=png, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=ppm, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=tiff, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=xbm, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=xpm, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=asciichess, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=docbook5, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dot, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dviluatex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=epub, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=platex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=literate, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=sweave, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=sweave-ja, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=r, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=knitr, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=knitr-ja, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lilypond-book, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lilypond-book-ja, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=latex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=luatex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdflatex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=xetex, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=latexclipboard, flags=16
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=text, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=text2, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=text3, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=text4, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=textparagraph, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=beamer.info, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lilypond, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=gnumeric, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=excel, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=excel2, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=xhtml_table, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=html_table, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=oocalc, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=xhtml, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=bibtex, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=eps, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=eps2, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=eps3, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=ps, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf2, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf3, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf4, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf5, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf6, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf7, flags=3
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf8, flags=3
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdf9, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dvi, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=dvi3, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=html, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=noteedit, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=odt, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=odt2, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=odt3, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=sxw, flags=3
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=rtf, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=word, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=word2, flags=7
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=csv, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=fax, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx13x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx14x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx15x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx16x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx20x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx21x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx22x, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyx23x, flags=5
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=clyx, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=jlyx, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=klyx, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyxpreview, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pdftex, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=program, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=pstex, flags=0
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=wmf, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=emf, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=wordhtml, flags=1
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=gnuplot, flags=2
Format.cpp (82): New Format: n=lyxgz, flags=5
Format.cpp (372): Recognised Fileformat: png
Format.cpp (372): Recognised Fileformat: png
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: application/pdf -> pdf6
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: application/pdf -> pdf6
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (161): Token: 'filename'
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (161): Token: 'lyxscale'
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (161): Token: 'special'
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (161): Token: '\end_inset'
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: text/x-tex -> latex
Format.cpp (472):   will guess format from file extension: lyx -> lyx
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
GuiApplication.cpp (263): 
The image loader can load the following directly:

GuiApplication.cpp (273): bmp, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): cur, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): gif, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): ico, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): jpeg, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): jpg, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): pbm, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): pgm, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): png, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): ppm, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): svg, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): svgz, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): xbm, 
GuiApplication.cpp (273): xpm, 
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (81): LyX recognises the following image formats:
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): bmp,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): gif,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): jpg,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): pbm,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): pgm,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): png,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): ppm,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): xbm,
graphics/GraphicsCache.cpp (83): xpm,
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
graphics/GraphicsLoader.cpp (118): LoaderQueue: waking up
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (823): insetgraphics::latex: Filename = /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (868):     Opts = width=\maxwidth{\textwidth}
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (888):     Before = \includegraphics[width=\maxwidth{\textwidth}]
    after = 
insets/InsetGraphics.cpp (934): InsetGraphics::latex outputting:
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth{\textwidth}]{drawing}
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
graphics/GraphicsLoader.cpp (91): LoaderQueue: 1 items in the queue
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (421):   Converting it to  format.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (389): [CacheItem::Impl::convertToDisplayFormat]
    Attempting to convert image file: /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    with displayed filename: ~/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
Format.cpp (406):   got format from MIME type: image/svg+xml -> svg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (398): 
    The file contains svg format data.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to bmp
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to gif
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to jpg
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pbm
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (346): Unable to convert from svg to pgm
graphics/GraphicsConverter.cpp (125): Converter c-tor:
doc_fname:        /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/deleteme.lyx
    from_file:    /home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg
    to_file_base: /tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/CacheItem.WbNtlX
    from_format:  svg
    to_format:    png
graphics/GraphicsConverter.cpp (288): build_script ... 
graphics/GraphicsConverter.cpp (416): ready!
graphics/GraphicsConverter.cpp (150):   Conversion script:
--------------------------------------
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, shutil, sys

def unlinkNoThrow(file):
  ''' remove a file, do not throw if an error occurs '''
  try:
    os.unlink(file)
  except:
    pass

infile = "/home/my_user/Desktop/LyX_fails/drawing.svg"
outfile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg"
shutil.copy(infile, outfile)
os.chdir("/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/")
infile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg"
infile_base = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN"
outfile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.pdf"
outdir  = os.path.dirname(outfile)

if os.system(r'inkscape --export-area-page --export-type=pdf -o $$p' + '"' + outfile + '"' + ' $$p' + '"' + infile + '"' + '') != 0:
  unlinkNoThrow(outfile)
  sys.exit(1)

if not os.path.isfile(outfile):
  if os.path.isfile(outfile + '.0'):
    os.rename(outfile + '.0', outfile)
    import glob
    for file in glob.glob(outfile + '.?'):
      unlinkNoThrow(file)
  else:
    sys.exit(1)

if infile != outfile:
  unlinkNoThrow(infile)

infile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.pdf"
infile_base = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN"
outfile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.eps"
outdir  = os.path.dirname(outfile)

if os.system(r'pdftops -eps -f 1 -l 1 ' + '"' + infile + '"' + ' ' + '"' + outfile + '"' + '') != 0:
  unlinkNoThrow(outfile)
  sys.exit(1)

if not os.path.isfile(outfile):
  if os.path.isfile(outfile + '.0'):
    os.rename(outfile + '.0', outfile)
    import glob
    for file in glob.glob(outfile + '.?'):
      unlinkNoThrow(file)
  else:
    sys.exit(1)

if infile != outfile:
  unlinkNoThrow(infile)

infile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.eps"
infile_base = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN"
outfile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.png"
outdir  = os.path.dirname(outfile)

if os.system(r'magick ' + '"' + infile + '"' + '[0] ' + '"' + outfile + '"' + '') != 0:
  unlinkNoThrow(outfile)
  sys.exit(1)

if not os.path.isfile(outfile):
  if os.path.isfile(outfile + '.0'):
    os.rename(outfile + '.0', outfile)
    import glob
    for file in glob.glob(outfile + '.?'):
      unlinkNoThrow(file)
  else:
    sys.exit(1)

if infile != outfile:
  unlinkNoThrow(infile)

fromfile = outfile
tofile = "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/CacheItem.WbNtlX.png"

try:
  os.rename(fromfile, tofile)
except:
  try:
    shutil.copy(fromfile, tofile)
  except:
    sys.exit(1)
  unlinkNoThrow(fromfile)

--------------------------------------

ForkedCalls.cpp (496): ForkedCallQueue: waking up
graphics/GraphicsLoader.cpp (129): LoaderQueue: I'm going to sleep

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:2): WARNING **: 12:25:45.529: Can't open file: /home/my_user/46208p/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:2): WARNING **: 12:25:45.529: Can't open file: /home/my_user/46208p/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/home/my_user/46208p/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/my_user/46208p/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.rLRffJbxxFlM/gconvertScGAXN.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
ForkedCalls.cpp (505): ForkedCallQueue: I'm going to sleep
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (272): Image conversion failed.
graphics/GraphicsCacheItem.cpp (281): Unable to find converted file!


For SVG -> PDF (Graphics), what if you change the command to the following? rsvg-convert -f pdf -o $$o $$i ? (and you would need to install the rsvg-convert program). Does that help?

Note that you can also find useful information by running lyx on the command line with -dbg graphics <yourfile.lyx>. Note that it is just one dash, and not two, before dbg.

@scottkosty I added the debug information.

After reading the configure.py script that ships with LyX, it seems LyX has changed its command-line options. Can you try with the following options? --file=$$i --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$$o

probably naïve, but lyx seems to think the file is under /tmp, whereas inkscape seems to be looking under /home/.../tmp and can't find the file.

try $$p$$o and $$p$$i instead of $$o and $$i. I'm guessing that' $$p is for path. it would help a lot if you didn't have writing obscuring the screenshots.

@scottkosty changing the converter SVG -> PDF (graphics) to inkscape --file=$$i --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$$o does not seem to change anything.

My only other idea is to install rsvg-covert, then go to tools > reconfigure, then restart LyX and see if that helps.

I think this is due to a bug in Inkscape actually, because it fails to open files that are outside the home directory from CLI, for example in the /tmp directory.

Does it fix things to change the temp directory (in Tools > Preferences > Paths) ?

@scottkosty thanks, I did not know about that option. That fixed my issues.

Great! Thanks for writing the steps up as an answer for others that have the same problem (there must be since the issue seems quite general!). +1.

TL;DR:

Crate the converter SVG -> PDF (graphics) with the following command: inkscape --export-area-page --export-type=pdf -o $$o $$i as shown here:


Now go to LyX→Tools→Preferences→Paths→Temporary directory and change it to ~/.tmp.

Now run mkdir ~/.tmp.

Restart LyX.


Now it should work.
Explanation:
Following all the suggestions from @scottkosty I managed to solve this. The problem was basically related to a bug from Inkscape that makes it fail when opening files from CLI that are outside the home directory. Consequently, every time LyX calls Inkscape in the /tmp directory, Inkscape crashes. The solution was in the end really simple: I set LyX→Tools→Preferences→Paths→Temporary directory to ~/tmp and now it works like a charm.
